# Reading multiple files to Distributed Cache in map -reduce

Tags: mapreduce, distributed-cache

I am currently trying to add two files to the Distributed Cache. However, when I am trying to read it, the second file is reading the same data as the first file although the two files hold completely different data. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely how you're actually configuring the job and then accessing them in the Mapper.  When you're setting up the job you're going to do something like

```
 job.addCacheFile(new Path("cache/file1.txt").toUri());
 job.addCacheFile(new Path("cache/file2.txt").toUri());
```

Then in your mapper code the urls are going to be stored in an array which can be accessed like so.

```
 URI file1Uri = context.getCacheFiles()[0];
 URI file2Uri = context.getCacheFiles()[1];
```

If that process of accessing your files isn't working there might be a problem with the actual files.

Comment: I'm using distributed cache. But when I try to read both files using:
Path p1=DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFile(context.getConfiguration())[0];

Path p2=DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFile(context.getConfiguration())[1];
Then value of both the path is the same although I am adding two different file

Comment: You're gonna have to do some debugging for a while.  Just try some things like adding more cachefiles or printing out all the results of the distributed cache.